# Django Foreign Key Related Objects Not Saving Changes, Cannot Edit

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have two models, Movie and Review. Review has a foreign key field related to Movie. I have been trying to edit the Review objects associated with an instance of Movie.

**models.py**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)

class Review(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**views.py**

```
    # Create and save movie object
    movie = Movie(title="Nightcrawler")
    movie.save()

    # Create and save two review objects
    review1 = Review(movie=movie, author="John", active=True)
    review2 = Review(movie=movie, author="Rob", active=False)
    review1.save()
    review2.save()

    print("Before: " + movie.title + " has " + str(len(movie.reviews.all())) + " reviews.")

    active_reviews = movie.reviews.filter(active=True)

    print("There are " + str(len(active_reviews)) + " active reviews.")
    movie.reviews.set(active_reviews)
    movie.reviews.first().author = "Abby"

    # Try and save both objects just for good measure.
    # Not sure if it is necessary to do this. Does not
    # seem to work anyway
    movie.reviews.first().save()
    movie.save()

    print("After: " + movie.title + " has " + str(len(movie.reviews.all())) + " reviews.")
    print("Author of the first review is: " + str(movie.reviews.first().author))
```

The output of the views.py code is as follows:

> ```
> Before: Nightcrawler has 2 reviews.
> There are 1 active reviews.
> After: Nightcrawler has 2 reviews.
> Author of the first review is: John
> ```

I want and expected the changes made to `movies.reviews` to be saved, but the output reveals that neither the `set()` method or changing the author value actually alters the Movie instance. Why are none of these edits being preserved?

Interestingly, the line `movies.reviews.first().delete()` does seem to actually remove the first review. I am curious why this works and the other changes do not.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the object, you should store it in a variable first

```
movie = Movie(title="Nightcrawler")
movie.save()

# Create and save two review objects
review1 = Review(movie=movie, author="John", active=True)
review2 = Review(movie=movie, author="Rob", active=False)
review1.save()
review2.save()

print("Before: " + movie.title + " has " + str(len(movie.reviews.all())) + " reviews.")

active_reviews = movie.reviews.filter(active=True).all()

print("There are " + str(len(active_reviews)) + " active reviews.")

movie.reviews.clear()
movie.reviews.set(active_reviews)

first_review = movie.reviews.first()
first_review.author = "Abby"
first_review.save()
movie.save()
```

It's not being saved because the object you updated is not the same with the object you saved because you ran another query by calling `first()` again.

If you intend to only keep the "active" reviews, you can use `remove` instead to remove inactive reviews.

```
movie.reviews.remove(*movie.reviews.filter(active=False))
```

`set` does not have any effect here because the `active_reivews` you passed as parameter is already linked or already set. If you want to stick with `set`, do a `clear` first.

Comment: This solution definitely preserves the changes, thank you. I had to add `null=True` to the Review model's foreign key Movie field in order for `remove` or `clear` to work.